# Access Symfony/Silex user data in security

Tags: security, silex

How can I access the currently logged in User's Id from the Symfony security session? I'm not in inside a class so `$this->get('security.context')->getToken()` doesn't work. Here is what hasn't worked so far:

```
$app->get('security.context')->getToken()
$app->getToken()
$app->secruity->getToken()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your spelling:

$app->**secruity**->getToken()  // You have written SECRUITY!!!

$app->**security**->getToken()  // Fixed Version

Maybe this is the reason that it's not working. The SecurityProvider component provides the following services:

- security
- security.authentication_manager
- security.access_manager
- security.session_strategy
- security.user_checker
- security.last_error
- security.encoder_factory
- security.encoder.digest

So I guess **security.context** will not work in silex...

As written in the documentation you can access the **SecurityProvider** instance by:

```
$app['security'];
```

To get the current user you can use:

```
$token = $app['security']->getToken();
if (null !== $token) {
    $user = $token->getUser();
}
```

For more information read the documentation of the [SecurityServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html)

Also make sure you have registered the SecurityServiceProvider within your app!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I read some docs on the Silex site but I'm not sure I was in the right place. And yes there was a typo, its not that big of deal.